# Msbuild property is not considered while passing as commandline parameter through powershell

Tags: powershell, msbuild, powershell-2.0, msbuild-4.0

I am trying to pass property through command line parameter ($args[0]) as follows using Powershell , but it is not being considered.

```
if ( Test-path -path $args[0]) {
            &"$MsbuildBinPath\Msbuild.exe" $MSBuildFile  /t:BuildAll "/p:AllComponents=$args[0]"  $Logger $ErrorLogger
            if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) {
                    Write-Host "It failed, send a mail"
            }
    }
```

If i pass the property like this follows, it is being considered.

```
"/p:AllComponents=List.txt"
```

Why command line arguments are not being considered when it applied directly?

I can store the command line value in some variable and pass but is there any other mechanism to pass it directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$args[0] is not expanded inside strings, you need to enclose it in a sub-expression notation:

```
... "/p:AllComponents=$($args[0])"
```

To avoid this syntax, assign the argument to a variable and embed the variable in the string:

```
$argsZero= $args[0]
... "/p:AllComponents=$argsZero"
```

For more information, type the following in your console:

```
Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules
```